# Force apps to be opened everytime in a new desktop

Tags: macos, applications, desktop

Is it possible to force an app that is being opened to be actually opened every time in a different desktop, so that the current desktop is not polluted with layered or stacked windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can set any app to launch in a specific Space.
It will open in the same one every time after that.

To get it there the first time

- Switch to that Space then launch it,

or if it's already running

- Right click it in the Dock > Options.
  Set to 'All Desktops'.
  Switch to your preferred Space - it will move with you.

Right click it in the Dock > Options. Set the Option to 'This Desktop'.

[image]

This method, of course, is not an automatic process & requires setting up by hand. One advantage is that you quickly learn which Space belongs to which app & can then use shortcut keys -  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>[number]</kbd>  by default.

Setting System Prefs > Mission Control to disable 'Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use' will make the assigned Space numbers stick.

[image]

This method will only work correctly if you don't manually move any app window to a different Space. Spaces cannot correctly handle apps split over more than one Space.

Answer (score 0):

It should remember your choice if you change it to fullscreen before quitting. Another option is to use the [Single Application Mode](http://tidbits.com/article/10624):

```
defaults write com.apple.dock single-app -bool true
killall Dock
```

Which may not be exactly what you want. I just tried on macOS Sierra and it's a little clunky- but still works.